# How do I make an Eclipse org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text component wider?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I think the question says it all.  I'm new to Eclipse plugin development, so I'm sure there's an easy answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final Composite area = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();

mTextWidget = new Text(area, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);

// Define a minimum width
final GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.widthHint = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
gridData.heightHint = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;
mTextWidget.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

This you can use to create a text widget and place it into a area (Composite)